# Pattern Match in an HTML Page

Tags: regex, pattern-matching, preg-match, preg-match-all

I have not been able to use preg_match for a page I need to mine data from. Get Contents on $url typically outputs multiple strings like below

> https://www.zigsaw.in/companies-detail/AU-Small-Finance-Bank-Ltd/65344.html

These strings can typically contain small characters, big characters, /, (, ), -, etc. I would want to extract the data

1. after the "company-detail/"
2. before  the ".html"

The code I have used is as below

```
$contents=file_get_contents($url);
$pattern='/\b(https://www.zigsaw.in/companies-detail/)\b+[a-zA-Z0-9.-()]+\b(.html)\b/';
preg_match_all($pattern, $contents, $matches);
var_dump($matches);
```

However, the above code is not fetching the desired result of

> AU-Small-Finance-Bank-Ltd/65344.html

& likeways

Comment: Can you check `preg_match_all("/[a-zA-X0-9\-]*/", $input_lines, $output_array);` https://www.phpliveregex.com/p/oR0 GOTO `preg_match_all` tab

Comment: First thing to do: display the warnings, read them and try to correct the problem(s).

Comment: @Sinto Gives a lot of results, most of which are not relevant

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte There are no errors. Just that it displays an empty array. 
What troubleshooting would you suggest for my case?

Comment: @ZigsawConsultancy: you have to pick the from the result by its index. OR you can check `preg_match_all("/companies-detail\/+[a-zA-X0-9\-\/]*/", $input_lines, $output_array);` https://www.phpliveregex.com/p/oR8

Comment: @Sinto Since the page contains a lot of such links, to identify the indexes would be another daunting task. Could you point our a more specific pattern?

Comment: There are 3 warnings due to the pattern: https://3v4l.org/fAVXF (once you will correct the first, the second will be displayed and so on).

Comment: Thank you for showing the right direction @CasimiretHippolyte and #Sinto et Hippolyte 
I was able to formulate the solution myself, based on help from the resources you redirected me to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TLDR:**

Use this: `\bwww\.zigsaw\.in\/companies-detail\/\K[^\/]+\/[^\/]+(?=\.html)`

**[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/DEkJTY/2/)**

**Explained:**

you have several problems on the regex

- Regexes are usually delimited by '/' caracters, so you need to scape those characters if you use them. For example, `http://` should be `http:\/\/`
- Although you won't get an error, you should scape the dot `.` to `\.` since dot means any character but new lines. So here `www.` you probably mean a literal dot: `www\.`
- You have this construct: `\b+` which is wrong. `\b` means bareword and `+` is repeat one or more times. This combination does not make sense. You could fix the error by scaping the `+` to be a literal +: `\+` however, since I don't think that helps you at all on your regexp, I would simply delete them
- On `[a-zA-Z0-9.-()]` you should scape the last `-` to `\.` since the dash is used for specifying ranges (like in a-z). Another option would be to put it at the end like this: `[a-zA-Z0-9.()-]`

With the above fixes you'll get: `\b(https:\/\/www\.zigsaw\.in\/companies-detail\/)[a-zA-Z0-9.()-]+\b(.html)\b` but that still doesn't match. And that is because the character class `[a-zA-Z0-9.()-]` does not allow bars `/` to occur.

So here, `https://www.zigsaw.in/companies-detail/Foo-BAR-Bank/12345.html` when you match `https://www.zigsaw.in/companies-detail/Foo-BAR-Bank` you cannot "go on" matching and later on you expect to find .html, which is wrong. So the regexp fails.

You cloud fix that by adding a bar to the class, like this:

`\b(https:\/\/www\.zigsaw\.in\/companies-detail\/)[a-zA-Z0-9.()\/-]+\b(.html)\b`

or you could just use: `\b(https:\/\/www\.zigsaw\.in\/companies-detail\/)[^\/]+\/[^\/]+\b(.html)\b`, which changes the class by `[^\/]+\/[^\/]+` which means any character that is not a bar, repeated one or more times, a bar, then any character that is not a bar repeated one or more times.

We also remove the `\b` before .html, since it does not add anything.

Now you have tthe problem of just matching the things you are interested in. You could add a capturing group like this `\b(https:\/\/www\.zigsaw\.in\/companies-detail\/)([^\/]+\/[^\/]+)(.html)\b` and revover second group.

However you can also do it without capturing groups:

With `\K` We will ignore all previous matched data. And with lookahead we 'match without matching' (we just check some pattern for the next characters, we use it for `\.html`)

So you could use:

`\bwww\.zigsaw\.in\/companies-detail\/\K[^\/]+\/[^\/]+(?=\.html)`